# Listview scrollbars not visible in activity that has the Theme.AppCompat.Dialog theme

Tags: android, listview

I've got a listview inside a common layout. When the activity extends Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar the scrollbars for the listview show correctly, but when I put theme.appcompat.dialog theme for the activity the scrollbars do not show at all.

```
<ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pickingListView"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"/>
```

Comment: Pass scrollbar colour if you are overriding theme.appcompat.dialog

Comment: same result if you give android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white" . Same result if you give listview the style of Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: I am talking about dialog theme not about darkactionbar

Comment: there is no such thing as scrollbar color property. The scrollbar won't show for a listview that is inside an activity styled with dialog theme no matter what property you set on the listview in xml or in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give style to listview itself. Create new theme for listview in styles.xml with parent theme apptheme and your problem will be solved.

OR

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

Comment: did you at least read my posting ? I already had that property.